# Simple Backbone.js and Google Maps Rendering

Tags: backbone.js, google-maps-api-3

I'm having trouble rendering Google Maps (V3) with Backbone.js.

It fails to load when I navigate to map view (/#/map); however, the map somehow loads perfectly fine when I hit refresh in that map view url.

Relevant Code Below:

---

```
<body>
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <div id="content"></div>


    <script type="text/template" id="home_template">
        <a href="#/map">Go !</a>
    </script>

    <script type="text/template" id="map_template">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </script>
</body>
```

---

```
var MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#content',

    render: function() {
        var template = _.template($('#map_template').html());
        var init = function() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            mapOptions);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
        this.$el.html(template);
    }
});
```

---

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        ""      :   "home",
        "map"   :   "map" 
    }
});
var router = new Router;

var homeView = new HomeView();
router.on('route:home', function() {
    homeView.render();
});

var mapView = new MapView();
router.on('route:map', function() {
    mapView.render();
});

Backbone.history.start();
```

---

It seems that 'something' is missing when I'm switching views between home and map, but I'm not sure what that 'something' is. I believe I have combed through relevant questions, but cannot find the missing point.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

(P.S The Mapview part is taken from : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial
)

Comment: Is `#content` being removed when navigating to `mapView`?

Comment: Can you post your HomeView?  Do you have any custom cleanup code that calls this.$el.remove or anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here I guess

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

you are calling init on window.load, but when you switch between view, it will not refresh the page, and window.load never get triggered. I guess you need to change the way init happening, I could be able to suggest better if I have more information about DOM structure of the page.

Comment: This is true, this is exactly where the problem lies.